Unable to get postgressql working right with docker, operation error. the server terminated abnormally?
For some reason i'm having difficulties trying to get postgressql connected. I've read somewhere that when using postgresql from docker. The localhost changes to the service name. Which in that case looking at my yml file at the postgres definition
db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres_container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: voting
    networks:
      - app
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
      - "5433:5433"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

So upon looking at this definition, the localhost should be db as stated by the yml file
engine = create_tables_for_voting.create_tables("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres123@db:5433/voting")
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()

This didn't work either as indicated by
There was an error when connection to db: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db" to address: No such host is known. 
So i figured why not try use localhost, so upon doing that
 There was an error when connection to db: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally
My final idea through again reading others problem. There was one individual who had an issue that port 5432 kept being used by another instance. Hence why the extra port definitions
I've been at this for hours, if anyone can guide me through it

Where is your client running?  The standard PostgreSQL port is 5432; what do you expect port 5433 to be the couple of places it's mentioned?

Adding an extra port mapping doesn't cause the software to become configured to listen on that other port.

@DavidMaze The other post i saw was about how they had one past configuration always listening to the same port even though they killed the process. Hence why they mentioned port 5433. I managed to fix it somehow, what i ended up doing was adding a network and it seemed to have worked after that. Still unsure what the problem was but incase anyone goes through the same thing.  Make sure your service name is the host name. Make sure port 5432
